# svn info vs svn log discrepency

Tags: svn

Subversion is giving me some confusing, and even conflicting, results. I'm trying to get the most recent commit number, date, and author for a bunch of files. The revision number for the repository and working copy is 6189.

`svn info path/to/file` is giving me

- Schedule: normal
- Last Changed Author: bobby
- Last Changed Rev: 5448
- Last Changed Date: 2012-01-03 11:37:56 -0800 (Tue, 03 Jan 2012)
- Text Last Updated: 2013-01-27 20:10:08 -0800 (Sun, 27 Jan 2013)

But, when I check that with `svn log path/to/file` I get some different results:

- r5509 | alice | 2012-01-27 07:54:57 -0800 (Fri, 27 Jan 2012) | 3 lines

I've looked at the diff for revision 5509, but I cannot see any mention of the file.

Can anyone suggest what's causing the difference? Revision 5448 does have changes to the file, so I think I'll trust the output of `svn info` but I'd like to understand why `svn log` is giving different revision numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `svn log FILENAME` you'll get **list of revisions**, which affect `FILE`. In case of FILE in WC and WC not updated to HEAD from repo, you'll get partial history

If you want get transparent and relevant results, use commands for sources inside repository

**Sample**:

URL is http://mayorat.ursinecorner.ru:8088/svn/Hello/trunk/Hello.fr.txt

```
>svn log http://mayorat.ursinecorner.ru:8088/svn/Hello/trunk/Hello.fr.txt -l 1 -q
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r35 | lazybadger | 2013-01-09 11:35:28 +0600 (Ср, 09 янв 2013)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

```
>svn info http://mayorat.ursinecorner.ru:8088/svn/Hello/trunk/Hello.fr.txt
Path: Hello.fr.txt
Name: Hello.fr.txt
URL: http://mayorat.ursinecorner.ru:8088/svn/Hello/trunk/Hello.fr.txt
Repository Root: http://mayorat.ursinecorner.ru:8088/svn/Hello
Repository UUID: 65c3f143-cc60-1d4e-9546-1f0378d96c08
Revision: 37
Node Kind: file
Last Changed Author: lazybadger
Last Changed Rev: 35
Last Changed Date: 2013-01-09 11:35:28 +0600 (Ср, 09 янв 2013)
```

("Last *" fields correlate to log-data)

---

Bonus-command

```
>svn ls -v http://mayorat.ursinecorner.ru:8088/svn/Hello/trunk/Hello.fr.txt
     35 lazybadg           90 янв 09 11:35 Hello.fr.txt
```